# Oracle ref cursor with slick

Tags: oracle, cursor, slick

All.

We have an Oracle package that returns a ref cursor:

> ```
>         CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY sandbox AS
>           FUNCTION my_function (text VARCHAR2) RETURN result_cv IS result result_cv;
>             BEGIN
>               OPEN result FOR SELECT MLS_SID FROM MLS;
>               RETURN result;
>             END;
>         END sandbox;
> ```

I am calling the function with the following scala code:

> ```
> lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
> database withSession {
>   val x = sql"select sandbox.my_function($text) from DUAL".as[(Int)]
>   x foreach (x => println(x))
>   Ok(String.valueOf(x.first))
> }
> ```

The code fails with the following error:

[SQLException: Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor]

The SQL statement works when I just use the select statement that is in the function (SELECT MLS_SID FROM MLS;), but when I open it as a ref cursor and return the ref cursor it fails.  I looked at the T4CResultSetAccessor and it only has one method getBytes().

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to make this work using the Oracle function call and ref cursors?  Thanks in advance.

-patrick

Comment: you cannot use the query this way. you have to make a  PL/SQL to call your function. Not sure how to do it in slick. Example exec ? := call yourpackage.function

Comment: I would suggest convert this function into a procedure with an OUT parameter for the ref cursor. Call this stored procedure from slick, there has to be some way to do this. Google it!

Comment: I tried ? = call creating essentially a 2 parameter statement, well slick set the first parameter to $text and then it errored out with "IN/OUT parameter 2 not set"

Comment: PLEASE cross-link if you double post. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/7uPwCYENjLA

Comment: I deleted my answer. Your SQL string is correct. I don't know how to do this with Slick, though...

Comment: Lukas, I wish you hadn't deleted your answer - turns out it's got us headed in the right direction. Our problem was not properly nesting the table.

Comment: It turns out that Lucas' solution was recommended by Typesafe.  Let me see if I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Frome Typesafe:

> Slick doesn’t support OUT parameters at the moment (which you would
>   need to properly return a ref cursor). If the cursor is all you need
>   to return from your stored proc, I suggest to use the method
>   recommended in the SO post: Lift the result set to the top level with
>   TABLE(). Does this work for your use case?

So our solution was to do this:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_function('text'))

We got an error, but that was Lucas' and Typesafe's suggestion